# Range based Search on date in astyanax

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

I have however, one more situation. In my Column Family I have rows with column for example name, salary, and dob(date of birth), All the columns are indexed. I want to do a range base Index search on dob. Will appreciate if you can let me know how can we do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could move from astyanax to playOrm and just do

@NoSqlQuery(name="findByDate", query="PARTITIONS p(:partitionId) SELECT p FROM TABLE p where p.date > :date and p.date <= :data");

you need a schema though that can be partitioned if you want to scale and you just query that single partition.  Some partition by customer, and some by time.  There are many ways to divide up the schema.

OR if you really want to use astyanax, playOrm does a batched ranged query where it gets all the columns in batches each time(so you don't blow out memory).  The code is on line 326 for setting up astyanax range builder and line 385 for using the builder to create your query.

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/blob/8a4f3405631ad78e6822795633da8c59cb25bb29/input/javasrc/com/alvazan/orm/layer9z/spi/db/cassandra/CassandraSession.java

Realize playOrm is doing batching as well so you see it setting the batch sizes too.

later,
Dean

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had a look at the code. It is doing a range based search on Key, For me i do not have a start and end key, all i have is two dates, one from Date and another to Date and i need to make a search on these values.  playOrm definitely looks good but at this point of time i am unable to switch to it.